# Анимация фона кнопки(Qpushbutton) в pyqt5

Tags: python, анимация, button, pyqt5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно каким-либо образом сделать анимированный фон кнопки `QPushButton`, используя для этого gif анимацию, или это в принципе не возможно? Необходимо, чтобы гифка работала постоянно, не в момент нажатия.

Или может как-то можно повторить функцию кнопки при нажатии на gif'ку?

p.s. возможно так: `self.button.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap('sample.gif')))` - открывается но изображение не подвижно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На счет кнопки не уверен, что уж точно нельзя сделать, но как по мне намного проще просто создать собственный класс с наследованием `QLabel` и в него запихать гифку при помощи `QMovie` и так же передавать нажатие сигналы для выполнения какой либо функции

**1.gif**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class GifImg(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, file_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.move = QtGui.QMovie(file_name)
        self.move.start()
        self.setMovie(self.move)
        self.setScaledContents(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit()


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label_gif = GifImg("1.gif")
        label_gif.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        label_gif.signal.connect(self.text_past)
        self.text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        layout.addWidget(label_gif)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def text_past(self):
        self.text.setText(self.text.toPlainText() + "\n123123")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Идея понятна, попробую реализовать

Comment: Может кому пригодится [ссылка на готовое приложение](https://github.com/samwl/Yes-No/blob/master/Y_N.py)