# Как в QPushButton вместо иконки вставить работающий gif?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, gif, qpushbutton

Собственно, погуглив полдня я понял, что примеров на *Python* практически нету, а в тех, что нашел, я так и не понял как это сделать.

Вот пример, кода где в качестве иконки картинка вместо этой картинки необходимо установить эту **`gif`**-картинку, но чтобы она начинала воспроизведение только тогда, когда на нее наведен курсор.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(155, 45)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 93, 28))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Python.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка :)"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Необходимо вставить эту gif:

> [image]

Comment: через qss пробовал?

Comment: @AlbionMuz А разве так можно? Я не выдел подобного.

Comment: Поидее можно gif картинки в background-image засовывать, я бы попробывал так

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает вариант через QLabel? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850595/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8qpushbutton-%D0%B2-pyqt5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша задумка может быть реализована примерно так, см. код ниже.

Обратите внимание, что я переопределил класс `PushButton`,
чтобы в нем переопределить:

> void QWidget::**enterEvent**(QEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован в подклассе для приема
> событий ввода виджета, которые передаются в параметре события.
>
> Событие отправляется виджету, когда курсор мыши входит в виджет.

> void QWidget::**leaveEvent**(QEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован в подклассе для получения
> событий выхода из виджета, которые передаются в параметре события.
>
> Событие выхода отправляется виджету, когда курсор мыши покидает виджет.

а также немного изменил геометрию `pushButton`:

```
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 130, 60))


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(155, 45)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton = PushButton(self.centralwidget)                             # !!!
        
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 93, 28))
#        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
#        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
#        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка :)"))


class ManagerCursor(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ManagerCursor, self).__init__(parent)
        self._movie = None
        self._widget = None
        self._last_cursor = None

    def setMovie(self, movie):
        if isinstance(self._movie, QtGui.QMovie):
            if not self._movie != QtGui.QMovie.NotRunning:
                self._movie.stop()
            del self._movie
        self._movie = movie
        self._movie.frameChanged.connect(self.on_frameChanged)
        self._movie.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._movie.finished.connect(self.restore_cursor)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        self._widget = widget

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        if self._widget is not None:
            self._last_cursor = self._widget.cursor()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def restore_cursor(self):
        if self._widget is not None:
            if self._last_cursor is not None:
                self._widget.setCursor(self._last_cursor)
        self._last_cursor = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        if self._movie is not None:
            self._movie.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        if self._movie is not None:
            self._movie.stop()
            self.restore_cursor()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_frameChanged(self):
        pixmap = self._movie.currentPixmap()
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap)
        if self._widget is not None:
            if self._last_cursor is None:
                self._last_cursor = self._widget.cursor()
            self._widget.setCursor(cursor)
        
        
class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):                                            # !!!
    def __init__(self, paren=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(paren)  
        
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("img/Fo2BxBK.gif"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 60))                                      # !
        self.setIcon(icon)

    def enterEvent(self, event):                                                    # !!!
        self.window()._manager.start()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):                                                    # !!!
        self.window()._manager.stop()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 130, 60))                  # !

        self._manager = ManagerCursor(self)
        movie = QtGui.QMovie("img/Fo2BxBK.gif")  
        movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 60))
        self._manager.setMovie(movie)
        self._manager.setWidget(self)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(190, 80)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Update

> Гифка появляется за курсором, но она должна стоять там на месте

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(155, 45)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка :)"))


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):                             
    def __init__(self, paren=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(paren) 
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie("img/Fo2BxBK.gif")
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 60))
        self.setMovie(self.movie)        
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):  
        self.movie.start()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.movie.stop()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):           
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QMouseEvent, QtWidgets.QWidget)
    
    def __init__(self, paren=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(paren)    
        self.setFixedSize(150, 65)
       
        self.label = Label() 
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Кнопка :)') 
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay.setSpacing(0)
        hlay.addWidget(self.label)
        hlay.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label.movie.start()
        self.label.movie.stop()  

        for w in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
            w.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.clicked.emit(event, watched)
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(watched, event)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.widget = Widget() 
        self.widget.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Clicked !!!'))
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)


qss = '''
QWidget>#label {    
    margin: 0px;
    background: #7189DB;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
}
QWidget>#label_2 {            
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font: 11pt;
    background: #7189DB;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
QWidget {
    background-color: #e77;
}
'''
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                     
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(190, 80)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гиф появляеться за курсором но она должна стоять там на месте

Comment: @12345 я добавил другую реализацию вашей задумки, проверьте.